# Outlook addin for executing Python script

Tags: python, outlook

I am working on a Python script that can be called from outlook
The script is compiled to executable via pyinstaller
I wanted to ask if it's possible to somehow achieve the following 
When a user right clicks he sees an option to run the script OR the user has selected an email and can call the script via a tool bar button
The script is called with two arguments 1-mode(which is add or search) 2- subject of email

Is it possible to automate this via outlook ? 
I was able to make a rule to execute script but I am not able pass on arguments to it

Thanks
Saad

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452288/how-can-i-extract-and-save-csv-file-attachments-from-outlook which has links to other similar questions